# RegExp : How to exclude a prefix string?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to match any string that contains the words "name" and "Richard" (in this order) that are not preceded by the word "hello".

**The Regexp should match** :
my name is Richard
name Richard
etc.

**But it should not match** :
hello, my name is Richard
#hello, my name is Richard
Richard name
etc.

**I tried the following Regexps but they don't work properly** :
(^hello).*name.*Richard
(?<!hello).*name.*Richard
(?<=^hello).*name.*Richard


**Thanks for your help** !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a single regexp:

```
^((?<!hello).)*name.*Richard
```

Play with it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pdysUb/1)

Responding to @Mateus comment: yes, this regex matches `name hello my name is Richard`. You can prevent that match with:

```
^((?<!hello).)*name((?!name).)+Richard
```

Check this one on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pdysUb/2) as well.

Comment: Your regex matched "name hello my name is Richard", is it supposed to be matched?

Comment: You should address this question to OP. I'm answering the question based on his examples. It doesn't match "something hello my name is Richard" at least.

Comment: @Mateus I've updated  my answer with a response to your comment.

Comment: Yeah, I see... +1 for such a small expression for this problem.